# Ошибка "Unable to execute command chcp" при попытке открыть базу данных

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Не могу открыть базу данных SQL.

Пробовал через SQL браузер выдавало ошибку, что нужен ключ шифрования SQL cipher как это можно обойти?

Текст ошибки:

> **Could not acquire management access for administration**
>
> RuntimeError: Unable to execute command chcp. Please make sure that the C:\Windows\System32 directory is in your PATH environment variable.

[image: скриншот1]

[image: скриншот1]

Comment: Пробовали перевести текст ошибки? В ней написано, чтобы вы убедились, что директория `C:\Windows\System32` находится в переменной окружения `PATH`.

Comment: Пробовали нажимать на кнопку `Settings...`?